# Qt Serialization no match for operator << operand types are 'QDataStream'

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, qdatastream

I have a problem during serialization with a simple Managed Structure.

My Class Header

```
class MappySaver
{

public:
    MappySaver();

    //structure
    struct Tile
    {
    public:
        int ID;
        int x,y,w,h;
        QRect rect;
    };

    QList<Tile> Tiles;
    QObject t;
    Tile tile;

};

QDataStream& operator << (QDataStream& s, const MappySaver::Tile& tile);
QDataStream& operator >> (QDataStream& s, MappySaver::Tile& tile);


#endif // MAPPYSAVER_H
```

and source cpp

```
   QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &s, const MappySaver::Tile& tile)
{
    s << tile;
    return s;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get this error:

> error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'const MappySaver::Tile')

```
template <typename T> //QDataStream.h
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const QList<T>& l)
{
    s << quint32(l.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
        s << l.at(i);
    return s;
}
```

I use this class to serialize a list.
On the main form, I have a widget with the same data.

And I use this method for try to serialize.

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                tr("Seleziona il file da salvare"),"",
                                            tr("File Mappa (*.mp2d)"));

MappySaver::Tile t;
    MappySaver m;


    for(int i = 0; i < ui->maps->Tiles.count(); i++)
    {
        t.ID = ui->maps->Tiles[i].ID;
        t.h = ui->maps->Tiles[i].h;
        t.rect = ui->maps->Tiles[i].rect;
        t.w = ui->maps->Tiles[i].w;
        t.x = ui->maps->Tiles[i].x;
        t.y = ui->maps->Tiles[i].y;

        m.Tiles.append(t);
    }



        QFile f(filename);

         if(!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
         {

         }else
         {
             QDataStream out(&f);
             out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);

             out << m.Tiles;

         }

        f.flush();
        f.close();
```

How can I fix this problem and serialize?

Comment: At first glance the compiler tells you what's wrong. You wrote functions for `MappySaver` but pass `MappySaver::Tile` as argument.

Comment: just create the function QDataStream& operator << (QDataStream& s, const MappySever::Tile& tile);

Comment: @AlexanderChernin i have an error  Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @giovannimannuoio Err... segmentation fault... but it doesn't describe the new problem. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53445245/edit) your question and update it with your attempt and the segfault error?

Comment: Full Source of Segementation Fault error  https://pastebin.com/c9ry9SBr

Comment: The compiler's got to be pointing you somewhere... did you try debugging which part of the code is providing the segfault?

Comment: The error is at   QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &s, const MappySaver::Tile& tile)
{
    s << tile;  //Here

Comment: Yep, you're getting recursion there. The function is calling itself. More appropriately, you might be wanting to output individual `<< tile.ID`, `tile.x`, etc?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Yea! Work! Tanks a lot Trebuchet. i have changend whit your example and work!  https://image.ibb.co/f0FB5V/Immagine.png